# Break from a coffeescript javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, vimeo-api

I'm using the vimeo api which reports the progress of the video playing back every second from 0.0 to 1 when the video is complete.
I want to do something when the progress is 0.66 or above but in my if loop whatever I want to do is fired continously once progress reaches 66% (0.66)

```
           player.addEvent 'playProgress', (data, id) ->
               break_loop = false
               if data.percent >= 0.66 && break_loop is false
                do_something
                break_loop = true
```

From when the video is at 66% progress to finished `do_something` fires every second, how can I just run it once?

Comment: What is the line `once == false` intended to do? (Unless Coffeescript is even weirder than I think it is, I suspect it does nothing at all.)

Comment: @pointy I thought it would break the loop after `do_something`

Comment: Well in your updated question, the code is worse: `break_loop = false` will **always** set the flag back to `false`, so setting it to `true` in the `if` statement does no good!

Comment: Sounds like you want a for or while loop....but it will execute every time the percentage is `>` 60% ...

Comment: @Pointy got it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend updating your code to use the [new Vimeo JavaScript API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js) so that you could use [`off`](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#offevent-string-callback-function-void) to remove event handlers. Then you could move your event handler to a named function (or at least the closest thing CoffeeScript has to named functions) and that could unbind itself when the 66% mark is reached, something like:

```
progress = (data) ->
  return if(data.percent < 0.66)
  do_something()
  player.off('timedupdate', progress)

player.on('timedupdate', progress)
```

Not only do you get an up-to-date interface but you also learn a fairly common pattern with JavaScript callbacks.

There might be something like `off` in the old API you're using but I can't find any documentation for it.